# How do I defeat the Gatekeeper as a Tank? (The 'Fortitudo' option?)

Tags: the-secret-world

I've completed all 8 Elite dungeons, and have Blue QL 10 Talismans in every slot! Obviously, the next step is Nightmare modes! But in order to run those, I have to first defeat **The Gatekeeper**. I'm primarily set up as a Tank (Blade/Chaos if it's important).

How do I defeat this mode? I've figured out that I need to keep him faced away from the green dude that's going to kill him for me, but he seems to periodically one shot me and I just can't avoid it. What am I missing? Are there further phases or mechanics to the fight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a video that shows the Gatekeeper fight as a tank;

As you mention you need to ensure that 'A friend' (the green dude) is behind the Gatekeeper, so that when he performs his 'Burning Light' attack your friend isn't destroyed.

I think the ability you have been one shot by is the 'Gaia Core' ability which can be seen in the above video being cast at approximately 1 minute 3 seconds - this ability seemingly hits for far more health than you'll ever have (1099681 in some combat logs) as *filth* damage, and needs to be interrupted.

As the fight progresses the Gatekeeper will spawn minions, which also need to be tanked, but don't need killing.

Answer (score 1):

When fighting the Gatekeeper in with a melee stance, you need to have 2 impaired active melee abilities. I would suggest not using an active healing ability because you will not have enough time. It is important to use your healing drinks instead and to use them very early in the fight because you have a 90 second cooldown and you will have an opportunity to use 2 healing potions if you have high health as in above 11,000. Attack rating does not help with the amount of damage you deal as compared to the Gatekeepers hit rate against you. If you are using blade and fist weapon, I would reccomend 3 strong active melee abilities for your first three slots, and then use Steel Echo (blue), Trial by Swords, Martial Discipline (Blue), and Stunning Swirl as an elite ability. If you are using a quantum brace you need to aquire the auxilary weapon toolkit to upgrade your weapon to one level higher from common to rare. If you do not have the 8th slot open for an auxilary weapon I would suggest completing the quest.

Answer (score 0):

The Gatekeeper fight seems to have been changed a bit. At the start you will get a buff called "**Heal Suppressor**" that ***cannot be cleansed or cleared***. It suppresses all heals from active abilities, passive abilities, leeching and even gadgets. The only thing that works is healing potions.

This means you should ignore advice about heals like Immortal Warrior, Forged in Fire, or Leeching mentioned in older guides. Instead focus on abilities that boost your block, evasion and protection. Apart form that the old guides are still valid: Dodge the column attack and impair Gaia Core. Quickly get aggro from the adds when they spawn (you don't need to kill them, they do very little damage to you) to protect your green friend. The Gatekeeper will knock you down and reset aggro at one point so be prepared to get it back as fast as you can (rocket jump, flamethrower or mass provocation works fine).

You will probably want to drink a barrier potion at the start to prevent some damage and then a healing potion when 90 seconds have passed. This is the build I used to pass the fight:

*Actives*

- **Grip Whip** to attack Gatekeeper (boosts block)
- **Escalation** (to draw aggro from adds when they spawn)
- **Dragon's Breath** (to aggro adds after being knocked down)
- **Illusion** (boosts evasion)
- **Chaotic Pull** (impair)
- **Helter Skelter** (impair)

*Passives*

- **Hardcase** (boosts protection)
- **Cool, Calm & Collected** (reduces damage after successful block)

*Stats*

- Attack rating: 99
- Health: 10204
- Block rating: 368
- Evade rating: 91